# Página en blanco después de 0.5 segundos usando React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy creando una App con React, algunas depedencias y Sanity. Me surgio un problema, cuando corro la App usando "npm start" me sale la App por 0.5 segundos y luego se me ve en blanco. Me muestra el NoScript. Pero si corro la página en mi Network sí funciona. Creo que el problema viene por Sanity.

Comment: Hola, es difícil ayudarte si no colocas el código que estas utilizando.

Comment: Si la página se te queda en blanco es que hay un error. En la consola del navegador debería de aparecerte el error que tienes.